# create-react-app + configs for endpoints/keys

Tags: node.js, reactjs, webpack, create-react-app

I am using 'create-react-app' npm from React starter https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript-React-Starter,

How do I have different config files for different environments (e.g. Dev, CI, production)? I want to store the endpoints, some app settings in those config files.

The only way that I can think of is to eject the project (npm run eject) and create the config json file using web pack.

Is there any better way to handle the different config files with 'create-react-app' npm? Thanks.

Comment: You want different `tsconfig.json` files for different environments?

Comment: different endpoints or app setting for different environments.  For example: If I run it on local, I might want to call http://localhost/api , if it's on CI, I might want to call http://myci-api-website.com/api/

Comment: did you solve this?

Comment: Did you end up solving this?